# Jenkinsfile is not taking the build job parameter from job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I don't why Jenkinsfile is not taking the parameterized value from the job. I have this parameter `$BUILD_UI`.

[image]

Jenkinsfile:

```
stages {
        stage("Prepare") {
            when {
                expression { return $BUILD_UI == 'true' }
            }
            steps {
                checkout([$class: 'GitSCM',
                            branches: [[name: '$UI_BRANCH_NAME' ]],
                            extensions: [[$class: 'CleanCheckout'],
                                            [$class: 'SubmoduleOption',
                                            disableSubmodules: false,
                                            parentCredentials: true,
                                            recursiveSubmodules: true,
                                            reference: '',
                                            trackingSubmodules: false],
                                            [$class: 'RelativeTargetDirectory',
                                            relativeTargetDir: 'defender-ui/']],
                            userRemoteConfigs: [[
                                url: 'git@bitbucket.org:xxx/xxxxx.git',
                                credentialsId: 'xxxxxx-xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx'
                            ]]
                        ])
                
            }
        }
```

But I keep getting this error. This is not working `return $BUILD_UI == 'true'` :

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: $BUILD_UI for class: groovy.lang.Binding
    at groovy.lang.Binding.getVariable(Binding.java:63)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onGetProperty(SandboxInterceptor.java:270)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$6.call(Checker.java:291)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:295)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:271)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:271)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:271)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.getProperty(SandboxInvoker.java:29)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyAccessBlock.rawGet(PropertyAccessBlock.java:20)
    at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:13)
```

Answer (score 1):

You must remove the $ from the variable name, so it will read:

```
return BUILD_UI == 'true'
```

This is because you are accessing the variable directly on groovy, without needing to expand it